# Can a 3rd party JS app submit HTML snapshots?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

I am relatively new to the world of HTML snapshots and JavaScript so I apologize if this is not that hard.

The app we make at our company uses JavaScript to dynamically load image and text content on to a webpage.  As you know, JS rendered content doesn't get indexed by search engines.  However, I have learned of the otpion called HTML snapshots where you can feed to Google and other search engines all the rendered HTML of the page and it will consume it as long as you follow their guidelines.

My question is that since my script is a 3rd party script that can be embedded on x amount of pages, can I still somehow leverage HTML snapshots or will my clients need to do that?

Comment: It's likely that your clients will need to do that themselves. However, Google has recently [started parsing javascript](http://www.business2community.com/seo/googles-crawler-now-understands-javascript-mean-0898263) which means the bot can read your page even if the content is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not work with this technology yet, I believe it depends by your application and by whom create the data (your client server or you library).

If a lot of content is generated at server side level, server should creates the snapshot.
If a lot of content is generated/manipulated at client, client could creates a HTML snapshot. For example using HtmlUnit.

More info on this page:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot